# Using pip install without internet connection

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I've wrote a Python program which uses external open source libraries. I've used the wheel library to make a package out of the scripts I've wrote.
My machine is offline and My problem is when I'm trying to upgrade a version, I cant reach the external open source libraries. important to say - I do have those libraries on machine and I'm not interested of upgrading their versions, just to update the package according to my modification in my Python code.

If I could get some help how to do it, that would be helpful!

Thank you,
Nir

after using the command:

python setup.py bdist_wheel

and:

pip3 install --upgrade -t /opt/PATH_TO/pip_install_dir/ file.whl

I get the following reasonable message:

```
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/wheel/dir/ --upgrade -t /opt/PATH_TO/pip_install_dir/ file.whl`